# Does eating snow help dehydration?

Tags: survival, snow, hydration

I have heard many people say that eating snow actually can increase dehydration since the energy required for the body to heat up and melt the snow is greater than the benefits received from the moisture in the snow.

Truth or fiction? And please back it with solid physiological evidence.

Comment: Good question! I also had kind of dry feeling when I tried to eat snow... :-)

Comment: Note: Precipitation (snow/rain) may contain some pollution, but essentially it is distilled water since it evaporated first and then fell to earth, therefore it is relatively clean and safe to drink, unlike pond water.

Comment: it doesn't cause dehydration, but it contributes to [hyponatremia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponatremia), i.e. lack of electrolytes in the blood.

Comment: My understanding is that most water lost in moderately or severely dehydrated people is through water vapor breath and sweat. The amount of energy needed to vaporize water is about 4 times than melting and heating -40 snow to 37. So snow isn't much different than water. So hold off the snow until moderate dehydration?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The calories to melt even frozen water are pretty small, and the water gained is certainly greater than that used to aid the use of those calories.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorie

So 1 calorie = 1 degree celcius (roughly with minor variation).  Okay easy.  Except it takes 80 times that to melt it initially.  Screw snow, let's figure on ice cubes.

1 liter of water frozen to ice at 0 °C
1 liter water = 1 kg water, (1000g * 80) 80,000 calories to melt the ice and then 37500 for the next 37.5° (to achieve 37.5 °C, temperature of the human body)

117500 little c calories

That's 117.5 dietary calories, because a dietary calorie is actually a kilocalorie.

How much water does it take to process 117.5 dietary calories?  No where *near* a liter or we'd all be dead the next time we ate a christmas supper.

But if you're *still* in doubt... well average daily intake is 2000 calories.  So if we assume ice is net negative then it must take more than a liter of water per 117.5 calories... which means that the human daily intake of water would need to be **17 liters**.

Based on [this article](http://www.chow.com/food-news/54270/does-drinking-ice-water-burn-calories/), but researched and did all the math myself to fact check it.

Comment: This looks correct to me (except it assumes 100% digestion efficiency, and that doesn't alter the conclusion). Eating snow definitely hydrates. It also shows that eating 500ml worth of ice/snow could drop your body temperature around 1/3 of a degree (C) in the short term. This might be significant if you're where you need to eat snow -- just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Ok... so it takes ~66 calories to warm up the water... But does that expenditure of calories have anything to do with hastening the body's use of water? The answer is almost there - but just needs to close the loop re: @xpda 's comment.

Comment: @LBell -- If expending 66 calories hastened the body's use of water enough to net negative on a liter of water, then we couldn't live.  It's already in the answer.

Comment: True - was just hoping for more "hard science" but I agree. I'll give it to you since this answer is the only one that provides hard, not anecdotal, evidence. Mind if I edit it a touch to crystallize the point?

Comment: How much more "science" does it get than math ;) -- Edit all you like, that's the point after all, get better answers

Comment: @RussellSteen I like math more than most people, but the experts have other practical information. For instance, the air-to-water ratio is the limiting factor in getting enough water from snow to survive. So, digging down deep in snow for a more compressed water source is vital to survival. I feel that should not be left out of the answer.

Comment: @theJollySin -- The question is about if eating snow causes net dehydration, not if eating snow in general is a good idea.  I agree that eating snow is not a good source of hydration, but it also does not cause dehydration.

Comment: I get [117 calories required to melt 1 kg of frozen water](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+kg+*+%28+334+kJ%2Fkg+%2B+37.5+C+*+4.18+kJ%2F%28kg+K%29%29+to+calories&a=UnitClash_*C.*DegreesCelsiusDifference.dflt--&a=UnitClash_*calories.*LargeCalories.dflt--&a=UnitClash_*kg.*Kilograms.dflt--&a=UnitClash_*kJ%2Fkg.*KilojoulesPerKilogram.dflt--&a=UnitClash_*kJ%2F%28kg+K%29.*KilojoulesPerKilogramKelvinDifference--). Of course, even at about 2x as many calories, you're still not looking at much water usage. Eating snow will cause hypothermia long before it causes dehydration.

Comment: Wikipedia gives 80Cal to melt 1g of ice. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_fusion

Comment: All, feel free to edit the answer :)

Comment: @RussellSteen I still don't get the conclusion. Who said the human body can survive (extract approx. 2000 kcal) from **only** destilled water (no matter if 30 or 300 litre a day)?

Comment: @Wills -- No one said that.  The question revolves around the amount of water necessary to process a calorie of energy.  So for snow to dehydrate the body it would have to use more water processing calories to melt snow than water gained from the snow.  That is not the case.

Comment: Another point to take from this is that if you are out of water but still have food, the increased food you would need is more important than the increased water you would need. The increased food required is still small, but might not be completely negligible like the water question. If you're in snow-eating survival mode, you're likely getting less than 2000 calories per day, so using snow in this way is more than 5% of your calorie usage. Possibly 10-20% depending on how hard you are rationing. So eating snow could make you need more carbs. Tangential, but related.

Comment: Of course, after considering my previous comment, I wonder if getting cold would shorten  your life more than increasing starvation. If you lower your body temp a few degrees, you might die tonight or tomorrow night, as opposed to dying days sooner (but still weeks away) from increased starvation. I'll leave it though, as maybe you are keeping warm by a fire such that the starvation really is your only immediate concern.

Comment: Burning carbohydrates and lipids (fat) actually *produces* water. While we need water to process food, it is not *lost* in that process. Dehydration (= need for more water) in itself is completely independent of your energy status. You can have enough water + energy, be lacking one but not the other (hunger or thirst), or both (hungry and thirsty). The situation where eating snow is not a good idea is exhaustion (hunger).

Comment: For 1 kg of ice, I arrive at 333 kJ melting enthalpy + 155 kJ for heating up to 37 °C, so 488 kJ = 117 kcal. Or, eating 2 kg of snow consumes about 1/7 of a 20-year-old 70 kg male's metabolic base rate.

Answer (score 47):

All the advice I've seen emphasises melting snow before consuming to avoid lowering your core body temperature (rather than, specifically, risking dehydration). If possible, melt the snow using a stove, or alternatively, pack the snow into a waterproof container and keep it in a pocket or your sleeping bag until it melts.

News stories such as [this one](http://www.oregonlive.com/pacific-northwest-news/index.ssf/2011/05/canadian_woman_who_disappeared_in_oregon_survived_on_snow_husband_missing.html), suggest that eating snow aided survival, however, I would guess there is a balance to be struck between succumbing to the effects of dehydration versus hypothermia which will depend on the environmental conditions.

Comment: In some cases you might **want** to lower your core body temperature. When hiking out or building a snow cave for example. Another issue to look for is getting sores in your mouth. As always there's no single right answer - moderation and good judgement are the key.

Answer (score 19):

As with any relatively unscientific field, there is a lot of lore out there that may have originally had a good scientific foundation, but the restrictions or specific conditions have long been forgotten and the answer takes on a life of its own out of context.  The myth about eating snow seems to me to be one of these things.

The main point is that it takes a lot of energy, which when coming from your body means warmth and/or calories, to melt water to drinkable form.  This is true, but the details are rarely considered.  Russell has already give an good answer going over the numbers to show that the energy required is relatively minimal.

However, another point I never see addressed is that the energy is often free.  If you're hiking up hill, even in winter usually, your body has to dump energy as heat.  If you're cold and facing hypothermia, eating snow is probably not a good idea.  Otherwise though if you're capable of dressing yourself so as to be too warm for whatever activity you are doing, you have excess heat that has to be gotten rid of somehow.  Therefore except in unusual cases, melting snow with your body warmth is free since you just end up cooling yourself off less in other ways.

I have experienced this personally.  Many years ago I was hiking up Mt Lassen in northern California in the summer.  I had taken insufficient water with me and was getting thirsty.  The weather was nice and I was hiking comfortably in shorts and a T shirt with a windbreaker in reserve in my pack.  When I got high enough so there were patches of snow, I kept some in my mouth and got water from that.  It definitely felt nice and made me less thirsty eventually.

The biggest problem you realize if you ever tried eating snow is that it takes a lot to get a reasonable amount of water.  You simply can't put that much snow in your mouth at one time, and there is a lot of air in it, so the amount of water you get from a mouthful of snow is very limited.  Still, it's better than nothing and makes you feel better.  It does slow you down noticably since you have to pause to pick up fresh snow for another mouthful regularly.  I suspect in warm conditions that you're barely replacing the water you are losing regularly anyway, but that's still better than losing it without replacing it.

So to me it seems that if you're thirsty and there is clean enough snow around, go ahead and "eat" it unless you are cold and hypothermia is a concern.  Dehydration, after all, is a serious problem too.

Comment: I'd not call the amount of energy minimal (considering that consuming 2 kg of snow to replace 2 l of water would correspond to about 1/7 metabolic base rate) but as you say: iff you actually have excess heat, it's going to help doubly: you get the water and don't need to sweat.

Answer (score 10):

If you can, melt it beforehand - not because of dehydration but because of the obvious; it'll cause you to get rather cold rather quickly!

If you can't and it really is an emergency (the only time I'd suggest it might be worth considering) then I haven't found a general consensus on whether it's a good idea, probably because it comes very much down to judging the situation - hydration vs. core body temperature. Do bear in mind that you won't get anywhere near the amount of fresh water from snow though so it may not hydrate you as effectively as you might be imagining.

One final point, never drink / eat coloured snow. I don't just mean the *obvious* cause of coloured snow - it can have all sorts of colours to it, and aside from the obvious this is most commonly caused by bacteria which are often rather nasty if ingested. This will almost always make the situation worse, not better!

Comment: So, would it be reasonable to think of eating snow off the ground as drinking untreated water from a puddle?  In terms of risk of bacteria/other pathogens?  (I know not as much will live in snow, I'm wondering what snow-borne pathogens can or will do to you if you ingest them).

Comment: @ClareSteen I've never been unlucky enough to be in that situation (fortunately!) The advantage with snow is that usually the bad bacteria turn it a different colour so you can tell not to eat it pretty easily. From what I've heard, it can essentially be like a very nasty stomach bug if you eat it. Definitely not what you want if you're out in the wilderness!

Comment: I filter or boil it before I drink water from melted snow.

Comment: Actually the most common cause of colored snow is algae, not bacteria.  However, your point remains.  Ingesting the algae can be bad.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, but it will really make you cold. It takes about 30 times more heat to heat water (melt ice) from 31 to 33 degrees (F) than it does to heat it from 33 to 35 degrees. That heat comes from your body if you eat snow.

Answer (score 7):

There are reported deaths from eating snow during WWII (Eastern Front).
I presume due to hypothermia and/or the general poor health of the soldiers concerned.

Another site points out that snow is excellent at catching polution.  Their reasoning is a bit fuzzy, but as a scientist I agree with their conclusion.

Comment: There is good information in this answer, but I would change it a bit to more directly answer the question. If you don't want to I would be happy to show you what I mean. Good start, and welcome to The Great Outdoors S.E.

Comment: Yeah, without being able to look at the original report, I am skeptical that they actually died of eating snow.  What other factors were envolved?  How do we know that eating snow was a contibuting factor, let alone the main cause?  What was the actual cause of death?  Was there a control in the same conditions where some ate snow and some didn't?  Were these people already hypothermic?  Would they likely have died anyway from other causes, like freezing to death?

Comment: @OlinLathrop: at the very least they were quite unlikely to be well fed, which basically means not far from hypothermia. And then the energy needed to melt and heat the snow may make a whole lot of a difference...

Answer (score 6):

The most authoritative source I know is the [Wilderness Medicine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1437716784) textbook, and it has some very useful information on this problem.

**Snow is mostly air.**

Let's say you stuff yourself full of snow. Unfortunately, the snow you eat is mostly air and not water. So it is extremely hard to get fully hydrated because though you get full, when the snow melts into water you only get a fourth or a fifth of the volume of the snow in water.

The solution to this is sometimes quite easy. Dig. If you have no choice but to eat unmelted snow for water, *dig down*. The deeper you dig in the snow, the more dense the snow is. And when denser snow melts it yields more water.

**Melt the snow first.**

Obviously, the ideal solution is to melt the snow first, so you can drink liquid water. The trick here is melting the snow. Wilderness Medicine includes a lot of case reports and has one definite conclusion: **PLEASE do not use your body heat to melt the snow**. You will increase your risk of hypothermia in a survival situation. Any other method to melt the snow would be extremely helpful to your survival.

Answer (score 6):

One point I would like to add to all the good answer before:

Snow is good at catching pollution. But it isn´t good in containg minerals. Apart from short-term hydration, you should NOT rely on snow as water source for a longer period of time because you simply won´t get the electrolytes you need - at least if you don´t supply them for example through food. This is also true for rain water and to some extent for ice.

Also I would like to point out, that Russels calculation may be right, but it doesn´t take into account *where* the heat is consumed. So it can be true that it doesn´t need to much heat, it can also be true that it lowers your core body temperature. I would try to melt it outside my body (e. g. in a bottle close to my body) or in the mouth, if necessary.